# How to 'thin' a database table out?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a large DB table which I am using for testing.  It contains 7.3m phone call records.  I would like to delete many of those, but still maintain a good spread over phone numbers and dates.  Is there any way of achieving this?  Maybe something to do with `table sample`?

Comment: What are your criteria for which entries to delete and which to retain?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Delete where the id finishes in a 1 or 6?  Or similar, depending on exactly how many you need to remove.

i.e. to keep just 10% of the records for testing delete all the records that don't end in (say) 7.

(Note that a delete like this could take a while.  You might be better doing a CREATE TABLE AS with just the records you need.)

Answer (score 3):

Copy the data you want to keep:

SELECT TOP 1000 * INTO dbo.Buffer
FROM Data.Numbers
ORDER BY NewID()

Delete all data:

TRUNCATE TABLE Data.Numbers

Move back the kept data

INSET INTO Data.Numbers(column list) SELECT  FROM dbo.Buffer